# UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable notification VS applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, delegates, data-protection

There are two ways to get notified when protected data becomes unavailable.

1. [applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623019-applicationprotecteddatawillbeco?language=objc) delegate
2. [UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationprotecteddatawillbecomeunavailable?language=objc) notification

**Are there any difference between these two approach?**

---

<sup>1. **applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable** - On a device that uses content protection, protected files are stored in an encrypted form and made available only at certain times, usually when the device is unlocked. This notification lets your app know that the device is about to be locked and that any protected files it is currently accessing might become unavailable shortly. If your app is currently accessing a protected file, you can use this method to release any references to that file. Although it is not an error to access the file while the device is locked, any attempts to do so will fail. Therefore, if your app depends on the file, you might want to take steps to avoid using that file while the device is locked.</sup>

<sup>2. **UIApplicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable** - Upon receiving this notification, clients should release any references to protected files. This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are essentially the same – just like the other `UIApplication` notifications that mirror the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods (e.g. `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, etc.)